# Mongo $Push in nested array

Tags: arrays, mongodb, nested

I want to add another element to the nested array but when executing the sentence do not find any coincidence

The sentence is the following:

```
db.classroom.update({
   _id:ObjectId("56a1276741c1375cd4e90b86"), 
   "code.user":{$ne:DBRef("user", 201309)}
 },{
   $push:{
     "code.$.user":{ $ref: "user", $id: 201308 }
   }
 })
```

And the collection

```
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("56a1276741c1375cd4e90b86"),
        "name" : "Desarrollo de Software",
        "comment" : "Salon destinado al Desarollo de Software",
        "code" : [
                {
                        "code" : "ABCDEF123456",
                        "user" : [
                                DBRef("user", 201309)
                        ]
                }
        ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I am reading your query correctly the find is mutually exclusive. You are searching where

```
{_id:ObjectId("56a1276741c1375cd4e90b86")}
```

and

```
{"code.user":{$ne:DBRef("user", 201309)}}
```

The `$ne` meaning NOT EQUALS (`!=`) and the document you have shown illustrates the object with that _id only has the the DBRef value you explicitly don't want.

I suspect just removing that second clause will get you farther:

```
db.classroom.update({
  _id:ObjectId("56a1276741c1375cd4e90b86")},
  {$push:{"code.$.user":{ $ref:"user", $id: 201308 }}})
```

Comment: I had already tried but Mongo sends me this message :
`The positional operator did not find the match needed from the query. Unexpanded update: code.$.user`

Answer (score 0):

> Try this one

```
db.classroom.update({
  _id:ObjectId("56a1276741c1375cd4e90b86")},
  {$push:{"code.$.user":{$each:{$ref:"user", $id: 201308 }}}})
```